# Centering a navbar in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've encountered problem with Bootstrap where I can't center my navbar on the page. The nav remains off-center, therefore my CSS is incorrect. Has anyone faced a similar problem with centering a navbar using Bootstrap.

Here is the html:

```
  <div class="container-fluid" id="main-section">
    <div class="jumbotron" class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
      <div class="row">
        <div >
          <h1 id="name-lead">Title</h1>
          <p class="lead">
            Info
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">link2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">link3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">link4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

here is the CSS:

```
.jumbotron {
  background: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 75px;
  margin-bottom: 75px;
}

.jumbotron .nav ul {
  display: inline-block;
}

.jumbotron .nav ul li {
  display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this to your CSS

```
.navbar-nav {
   float: none;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gysLuywg/)